# How to store dynamic form value into datastore using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I am creating a dynamic form in html template to obtain the currency pair that user select. The form looks like this:

[image]

The user can dynamically add and remove currency. I used a Jquery to generate different currency pairs name of currency_n for the nth currency.

My best question is how to store those into datastore.

If user only create one currency pair (i.e. The form is not dynamic), the get.request should be

```
    def post(self):
        user_currency_1_1 = self.request.get('currency_1_1')
        user_currency_1_2 = self.request.get('currency_1_2')
```

I didnt know how many currency pairs does customer submit, how to get the correct value? Also, how to design the datastore structure to store those dynamic content?

```
class currency(db.Model):
    user = db.EmailProperty(required = True)
    currency = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to even answer, as you have not responded to answers in your last question.  We are not here to write your code for you.  But, you are fortunate that SO users are generous with their time.

Following up on my last answer:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class UserCurrencies(ndb.Model):
    user_email = ndb.StringProperty()
    currencies = ndb.JsonProperty(indexed=False)
```